# Numbers recognition, neural net not working properly

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, neural-network

I'm doing an OCR project, trying to recognize numbers, at least.
I have Hamming neural network with two layers. If it will solve the problem, I'll post a source here.
The problem is that this network doesn'work properly, the result is always 1 and 7. By the way when changing standart images' size to 10x10 pix, it doesn't work either, but the numbers are 3 and 0 now.
So, i'd be very grateful if anyone could help me solve the problem, maybe there's something in general that could lead to this problems.
Of cource, if needed I could post my sourcecode.
I'm comparing very similar pictures now, that's why the problem's astonishing me.

Comment: This is far to vague. Try to be more specific. It is probably just a bug. I would suggest looking at the hamming distance algorithm and comparing known images that should be similar.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just can't figure out a problem by myself and afer searching I found a couple of similar posts(where no problem is stated), so decided to create mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very recently I had to implement the same thing in Matlab, and I got about 78% accurate result. I used 40x40 images, and constructed the feature vectors from the average values of a 3x3 to 15x15 box around each pixel. Maybe the small image size is the problem?

Comment: Hope so, I'll try firstly to surf through the code again, and then find better images. Thanks.